# Recursive generate JSON tree from table in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, common-table-expression

Running into problem while trying to generate json using recursive cte

My structure contains id and parent_id on the same table. The id is tie to the parent_id, and I won't know how deep the structure would go.

Here's the table and code I have created
https://dbfiddle.uk/DFCYOzUm

I did a fair amount of research and this is the closest solution I have found:

[Recursively generate JSON tree from hierarchical table in Postgres and jOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66656005/recursively-generate-json-tree-from-hierarchical-table-in-postgres-and-jooq)

this is what I am getting

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "1.1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1.1.2",
                        "children": [
                        ],
                        "unit_name": "C",
                        "randominfo": "C"
                    }
                ],
                "unit_name": "C",
                "randominfo": "C"
            }
        ],
        "unit_name": "A",
        "randominfo": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "1.1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1.1.1",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "1.1.1.1",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "1.1.1.1.1",
                                        "children": [
                                        ],
                                        "unit_name": "C",
                                        "randominfo": "C"
```

This the structure I am looking for, I want 1.1.2 and 1.1.1 to be under 1.1 :

````
{
        "id": "1",
        "children": [
            {
              
              {
                "id": "1.1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1.1.1",
                        "children": [
                            {
                               "id": "1.1.1.1"      
                               "children": [}
                            },
                           {
                               "id": "1.1.1.2"      
                               "children": [}
                            }
                        ],
  
                    },
                  { 
                        id": "1.1.2",
                       "children" []
                  }
                ],

            }
            }
        ]
}```


Any help would be appreciated!
````

Comment: Why do you expect to see a result with id `1.2` if this `id` is **not** in your data?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber 1.2 is a typo and thanks for pointing it out. I went ahead and updated my question, basically I want both 1.1.2 and 1.1.1 to be under 1.1 and not split into two.

Comment: You'll need to show us the SQL code you're using to produce that result, we cannot tell you what's wrong and what to adjust otherwise

Comment: @Bergi here it is. 
https://dbfiddle.uk/DFCYOzUm